# Remote trigger for (re)build CI Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to use a remote trigger for (re)building in ci.gitlab. For explaining this, I made up this scenario:

- 2 repository, "lib" and "app1"
- app1 will successfully build only if lib is included (solved simply by .gitlab-ci.yml)
- I need to trigger the build of app1 (only for the master branch, in best-case) on commit (or merge request) of lib

I tried to figure it out using web hooks, but I wasn't able to find a url for ci.gitlab.com. Is this possible in a gitlab environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with newly added triggers functionality.

In your CI's project, find the section "Triggers". Add a trigger and use its token like this:

```
curl -X POST \
 -F token=TOKEN \
 https://ci.gitlab.com/api/v1/projects/{project_id}/refs/REF_NAME/trigger
```

(https://about.gitlab.com/2015/08/22/gitlab-7-14-released/)

**Obsolete:**

we have the same problem, and the way we solved it is by pushing and subsequently deleting a tag.

The assumption is that you manage the machine with Gitlab-CI runner. First, clone the main repository, `app1` for you. And in `lib`'s `.gitlab-ci.yml` add the steps:

```
- cd /path/to/app1_repository
- git pull
- git tag ci-trigger master
- git push origin ci-trigger
- git push --delete origin ci-trigger
- git tag -d ci-trigger
```

Make sure that you have the option `Tag push events` checked in your Gitlab Services settings for Gitlab-CI.

This solution has drawbacks:

- Gitlab-CI runner must have write permissions to the repository, so it won't work for shared runners
- git history will be bloated with all this tagging (especially Gitlab UI)

I opened an issue for this (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci/issues/223) so let's hope they add this functionality to the API (http://doc.gitlab.com/ci/api/README.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It's little messy, as you point, but it's work.